# Check given number lies between range as defined inside mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let say I have a collection with schema

```
{
  _id:ObjectId("xx")
  bound:{min:123,max:999}
}
```

I have a number let say 200 i want return result which accept the condition of bound i.e. for 200 it should return object like as mention above.

I need a query to get required results.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issue are you running into?

Comment: I need query so that i can provide a number in return it will give result from collection which contain bound data.

Comment: No, I understood your question. I'm asking what you tried so far, for your query. Rather than "write this query for me."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i found solution
with given number 200 test within bounds.

```
db.collection("test").find({$and:[{"bound.max":{$gt:200}},{"bound.min":{$lt:200}}]})
```